# Enrich Json using Groovy

Tags: groovy

how do I enrich information from one JSON into another JSON using groovy based on a key value? As shown below based on the value of the key "Id" in MainJson, I need to look up "id" in SecondJson. When a match is found, I need to get the object "name" from SecondJson and append it to MainJson

MainJson:

```
[
{
    "webshop": [
        {
            "id": "1168190",
            "type": "segment",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "1168191",
                    "type": "application",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "1168192",
                            "type": "productRange"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1168193",
                            "type": "productRange"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1168194",
                    "type": "application",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "1168195",
                            "type": "productRange"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1168196",
                            "type": "productRange"
                        }
                    ]
                }                   
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

SecondJson:

```
{
"ProductCategorization": [
    {
        "code": "1168190",
        "name": [
            {
                "en": "Irrigation"
            },
            {
                "es": "Riego"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "1168191",
        "name": [
            {
                "ES": "Kenadrain"
            },
            {
                "EN": "Kenadrain"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "1168192",
        "name": [
            {
                "ES": "Fluxol"
            },
            {
                "EN": "Fluxol"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "1168193",
        "name": [
            {
                "EN": "PP System Jimten"
            },
            {
                "ES": "PP System Jimten"
            }
        ]
    }]}
```

Required Output:

```
[
{
    "webshop": [
        {
            "id": "1168190",
            "type": "segment",
            "name": [
            {
                "en": "Irrigation"
            },
            {
                "es": "Riego"
            } ],
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "1168191",
                    "type": "application",
                    "name": [
            {
                "ES": "Kenadrain"
            },
            {
                "EN": "Kenadrain"
            } ]
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "1168192",
                            "type": "productRange",
                            "name": [
            {
                "ES": "Fluxol"
            },
            {
                "EN": "Fluxol"
            }
        ],
```

I tried the below code, however, the JSON is just appended to the first JSON , instead of finding a match and appending the relevant object

```
     def json1 = message.getBody(String);
    def map = message.getHeaders();
    def json2 = map.get("category"); 
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def json1Obj = slurper.parseText(json1)
    def json2Obj = slurper.parseText(json2)
    json1Obj.each{  it.webshop?.each{  node -> node.name = json2Obj.ProductCategorization.findAll{item -> item.code == it.id }.name[0]
                                      it.values?.each{ node1 -> node1.name = json2Obj.ProductCategorization.findAll{item1 -> item1.code == it.id }.name[0]
                                                        it.values?.each{ node2 -> node2.name = json2Obj.ProductCategorization.findAll{item2 -> item2.code == it.id }.name[0]
                                                                    it.values?.each{ node3 -> node3.name = json2Obj.ProductCategorization.findAll{item3 -> item3.code == it.id }.name[0] } } } } }
   def out= JsonOutput.toJson(json1Obj)
   message.setBody(out);

    return message;
```

Comment: it sounds like you are answering your question: `I need to look up "id" in SecondJson. When a match is found, I need to get the object "name" from SecondJson and append it to MainJson`. What it the issue to implement this in code?

Comment: How do i look up for a match and add only the name object to the MainJson? i'm still a beginner in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive function to traverse the `main` to look for id and it's counterpart in the `second` JSON, the code can look like so:

```
import groovy.json.*

JsonSlurper sl = new JsonSlurper()

def main = sl.parseText '[{"webshop":[{"id":"1168190","type":"segment","values":[{"id":"1168191","type":"application","values":[{"id":"1168192","type":"productRange"},{"id":"1168193","type":"productRange"}]},{"id":"1168194","type":"application","values":[{"id":"1168195","type":"productRange"},{"id":"1168196","type":"productRange"}]}]}]}]'
def second = sl.parseText '{"ProductCategorization":[{"code":"1168190","name":[{"en":"Irrigation"},{"es":"Riego"}]},{"code":"1168191","name":[{"ES":"Kenadrain"},{"EN":"Kenadrain"}]},{"code":"1168192","name":[{"ES":"Fluxol"},{"EN":"Fluxol"}]},{"code":"1168193","name":[{"EN":"PP System Jimten"},{"ES":"PP System Jimten"}]}]}'                                                                           

Closure traverser
traverser = { o ->
  switch( o ){
    case List:
        o.each traverser
        break

    case Map:
        o.each traverser
        if( o.id ){
            def name = second.ProductCategorization.findResult{ it.code == o.id ? it.name : null }
            if( name ) o.name = name
        }
        break

    case Map.Entry:
        o.value.each traverser
        break

  }
}

traverser main

JsonOutput.prettyPrint JsonOutput.toJson( main )
```

prints

```
[
    {
        "webshop": [
            {
                "id": "1168190",
                "type": "segment",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "1168191",
                        "type": "application",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "id": "1168192",
                                "type": "productRange",
                                "name": [
                                    {
                                        "ES": "Fluxol"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "EN": "Fluxol"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "1168193",
                                "type": "productRange",
                                "name": [
                                    {
                                        "EN": "PP System Jimten"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "ES": "PP System Jimten"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": [
                            {
                                "ES": "Kenadrain"
                            },
                            {
                                "EN": "Kenadrain"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1168194",
                        "type": "application",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "id": "1168195",
                                "type": "productRange"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "1168196",
                                "type": "productRange"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": [
                    {
                        "en": "Irrigation"
                    },
                    {
                        "es": "Riego"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```